# Strange lightning - what is wrong with my model?

Tags: rendering

I am a total beginner in modelling but would claim to know the basics.
Here is how my model looks rendered in blender:

[image: blender rendered]

As you can see there are many strange ligthning artifacts, and the edge is not lit how one would expect. The beveled faces at the edges of this thing look weird, too. 
The normals seem to be correct (I also recalculated them):

[image: blender rendered]

So what am I doing wrong here? It is worth mentioning, that this only occurs when i triangulate the model. Before that, everything except of the beveled areas looked okay. The artifacts vary in size and intensity when i subdivide the faces even further.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you triangulating the mesh? You should try working with quads. Use loop cuts to add holding edges or select edge loops and add bevel weight and use the bevel modifier to get clean edges when using the subdivision modifier.

Comment: I used to bevel sharp corners and edges with the bevel tool in edit mode.. what is the benefit of using the modifier?
And okay, you both say i should not triangulate. While i accept this as an advice, i dont really understand how it can actually "break" the model.. The problem is also that some of this lighning glitches appear in unity, too, and unity triangulates automatically...

Comment: Beveling using either method is fine - it's a matter of preference - do you prefer destructive editing or non-destructive editing? By using the modifier, it's generally easier to make changes. Un-beveling and un-chamfering isn't exactly straightforward without the help of certain add-ons like MESHmachine. Manual triangulating isn't a good idea (IMO) because it makes creating clean mesh very difficult as the model increases in complexity. Your shading problems are likely coming from all of those corner poles pinching your mesh. Make a clean mesh and allow Blender/Unity to handle tessellation.

Comment: I prefer construction editing since I can see what i am doing at any time while editing. Maybe this is because I am not used to non constructive editing and am not familiar with blender modifiers... But of course you are right that changes become easier with non constructive editing...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try turning on this, and play with the angle setting.

This model is a bit of a mess though, so many triangles, some don't look planar, those things are going to ruin your shading. Try to keep everything as quad as much as you can.

Comment: so you say I should not triangulate my mesh? I thought (or heared from more experienced users) this would be better before importing to unity...
actually they are planar since i ran the clean up function for planar faces.
There are only so many triangles because i triangulated and then experimented with subdividing my mesh.

Comment: The auto smooth option for normals is turned on and different settings almost do not affect the outcome in any way.

Comment: Unity will triangulate the mesh by itself. Avoid doing it while modeling. Stick to quads for better results

Comment: Tris can be fine it's just how you use them that matters. If Autosmooth isn't working for you, it may be an issue with custom normals was this model imported into Blender or originally made in Blender?